# PuPHPet vagrant не запускается, виснет на: SSH auth method: private key (Windows 8.1 x64)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

Настроил образ в [puphpet](https://puphpet.com), распаковал и запустил `vagrant up`. В итоге доходит до `SSH auth method: private key` и долго висит, после чего пишет *"Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot..."*

```
            d:\Development\puphpet\machine1>vagrant up
            Bringing machine 'machine1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
            ==> machine1: Importing base box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x32'...
            ==> machine1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
            ==> machine1: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x32' is up to date...
            ==> machine1: Setting the name of the VM: machine1_machine1_1471466504051_65551
            ==> machine1: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 10200.
            ==> machine1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
            ==> machine1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
                machine1: Adapter 1: nat
                machine1: Adapter 2: hostonly
            ==> machine1: Forwarding ports...
                machine1: 22 (guest) => 5900 (host) (adapter 1)
                machine1: 22 (guest) => 10200 (host) (adapter 1)
            ==> machine1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
            ==> machine1: Booting VM...
            ==> machine1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
                machine1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:10200
                machine1: SSH username: vagrant
                machine1: SSH auth method: private key
            Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
            Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
            the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

            If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
            Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
            are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

            If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
            working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
            problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
            Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
            as well.

            If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
            the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

-

Так же попробовал без puphpet запустить бокс `puphpet/ubuntu1404-x32`? то же самое:

```
            d:\Development\puphpet\test2>vagrant init puphpet/ubuntu1404-x32
            A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
            ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
            the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
            `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

            d:\Development\puphpet\test2>vagrant up
            Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
            ==> default: Importing base box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x32'...
            ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
            ==> default: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x32' is up to date...
            ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: test2_default_1471464415949_48568
            ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
            ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
            ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
                default: Adapter 1: nat
            ==> default: Forwarding ports...
                default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
            ==> default: Booting VM...
            ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
                default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
                default: SSH username: vagrant
                default: SSH auth method: private key
            Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
            Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
            the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

            If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
            Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
            are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

            If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
            working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
            problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
            Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
            as well.

            If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
            the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

-

Взял первый попавшийся бокс не связанный с puphpet - `hashicorp/precise32`, сразу завелся:

```
            d:\Development\puphpet\test4>vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
            A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
            ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
            the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
            `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

            d:\Development\puphpet\test4>vagrant up
            Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
            ==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
            ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
            ==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
            ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: test4_default_1471466135068_6464
            ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
            ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
            ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
                default: Adapter 1: nat
            ==> default: Forwarding ports...
                default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
            ==> default: Booting VM...
            ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
                default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
                default: SSH username: vagrant
                default: SSH auth method: private key
                default:
                default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
                default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
                default:
                default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
                default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
                default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
            ==> default: Machine booted and ready!
            ==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
                default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
                default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
                default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
                default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
                default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
                default: your host and reload your VM.
                default:
                default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
                default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
            ==> default: Mounting shared folders...
                default: /vagrant => D:/Development/puphpet/test4

            d:\Development\puphpet\test4>vagrant ssh
            Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)

             * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
            New release '14.04.5 LTS' available.
            Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

            Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
            Last login: Fri Sep 14 06:22:31 2012 from 10.0.2.2
            vagrant@precise32:~$ exit
            logout
            Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

            d:\Development\puphpet\test4>vagrant ssh-config
            Host default
              HostName 127.0.0.1
              User vagrant
              Port 2200
              UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
              StrictHostKeyChecking no
              PasswordAuthentication no
              IdentityFile d:/Development/puphpet/test4/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
              IdentitiesOnly yes
              LogLevel FATAL
```

-

Попробовал включить gui:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.gui = true
end
```

Либо просто чёрный экран (редко), либо иногда виснет во время загрузки с надписью *Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...*, чаще всего загружается и запрашивает имя пользователя и пароль:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS vagrant tty1
vagrant login:
```

Comment: Если запустить машину не через `vagrant up`, а из самого VirtualBox, то по ssh подключиться к ней получается, но виртуалхосты не доступны и `private_network: 192.168.56.101` не пингуется.

Comment: Первую часть проблемы решил, дело было в интеловских адаптерах Intel https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3860
Теперь ubuntu грузится без проблем и по ssh сразу же удается приконнектиться. Но хосты всё ещё недоступны, 192.168.56.101 не пингуется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем добавил следующие опции, что бы заменить интеловские адаптеры:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "Am79C973"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "Am79C973"]
end
```

после этого заработала сеть.

Хосты не были доступны, поскольку Vagrant ничего не устанавливал (nginx, php и т.д.), не сразу догадался проверить. Видимо несовместим с VirtualBox 5.1. Сделал дунгрейд VirtualBox-а на 5.0 и всё завелось.

Всем спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

То же самое, о чем пишет user3137537, можно сделать и в конфиге **`puphpet/config.yaml`**.
Установить параметру `natdnshostresolver1`, которое по умолчанию `false`, значение `Am79C973`:

```
natdnshostresolver1: "Am79C973"
```